# How to get average of Categories if SubCategories are referenced in Result table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api2, data-access-layer

I am having problems in writing a LINQ for calculating average value based on not directly referenced column.

Provide background and tell us what you've already tried.

I have following tables, now I want average marks based on  category and subcategory, But fetching it through TopicId(FK) in Result table is going to be a big task.
 (I tried and couldn't figure out how to do it)

[Image having tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ari2E.png)

How Can I get average marks for Category and subcategory?

Comment: Start with `Result` and see if you can get that. Then work your way up to `Topic` and group by `SubCategoryID` and now you're almost there. Work your way up to `SubCategory` to get the `SubCategoryName`. Now you have the results grouped by sub category. Now move up to `Category`. You need to try if you want to learn. Try that and then edit your question with your code pasted and ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the SQL query that you need:

```
select 
    c.Id as CategoryId, 
    c.CategoryName,
    sc.Id as SubCategoryId,
    sc.SubCategoryName,
    AVG(r.Marks) as Average
from Result r
join Topic t on r.TopicId = t.Id
join SubCategory sc on t.SubCategoryId = sc.Id
join Category c on sc.CategoryId = c.Id
group by c.Id, c.CategoryName, sc.Id, sc.SubCategoryName
```

And this is the same with LINQ query syntax:

```
using (var db = new TopicContext())
{
    // build the query
    var query =
        from r in db.Result
        join t in db.Topic on r.TopicId equals t.Id
        join sc in db.SubCategory on t.SubCategoryId equals sc.Id
        join c in db.Category on sc.CategoryId equals c.Id
        group r by new { c.Id, c.CategoryName, SubCategoryId = sc.Id, sc.SubCategoryName } into gr
        select new
        {
            CategoryId = gr.Key.Id,
            CategoryName = gr.Key.CategoryName,
            SubCategoryId = gr.Key.SubCategoryId,
            SubCategoryName = gr.Key.SubCategoryName,
            Average = gr.Average(x => x.Marks)
        };

    // ToList() method executes the query, so we get the result on that line of code
    var result = query.ToList();
}
```

If you have an existing database you can use `EF Core` to generate your own `dbContext` (in my example this is `TopicContext` class) with the help of `Scaffold-DbContext` command. You can find an example of this command [on that page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db). To use this command you should install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` nuget package along with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`.